# Error when I try to apply Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

When I add one line below in AndroidManifest.xml, it doesn't work.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Like this.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I also tried to change

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

to

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
```

But still it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: The only way I could make it work is to change styles.xml file

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

Is this the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity { ...
```

ActionBarActivity change to **Activity**